# How to change default text in allow notification to xyz want to send notification in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I want to send notification for flutter web users, initially it asks the permission and it says localhost wants to send notification, but I want to change it to "xyz wants to send notification". Is there any way in flutter to do that, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!